# SAPUI5 - How to bind fields of child entity in same panel as fields of parent entity in SAP Friori Sample "Approve PO" app?

Tags: sapui5

In the SAP Sample "Approve Purchase Order" application, that comes with the SAP Web IDE, how do I bind fields of "Supplier" entity (child) in the same "Simple Form" UI container control as the fields of "PurchaseOrder" (parent) entity. In this sample, there are 3 separate mock data files, one each for "Purchase Order", "Purchase Order Items" and "Supplier". The relationship between Purchase Order and Supplier is 1:1 defined in the metadata.xml using association.

a)  PurchaseOrder (relevant portion only)

```
<EntityType Name="PurchaseOrder" sap:content-version="1" sap:is-thing-type="true">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="POId"/>
    </Key>
    <Property MaxLength="10" Name="POId" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String" sap:creatable="false" sap:filterable="false"
        sap:label="Purchase Order ID" sap:updatable="false"/>
    <Property MaxLength="10" Name="OrderedById" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String" sap:creatable="false" sap:filterable="false"
    <Property MaxLength="10" Name="SupplierId" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String" sap:creatable="false" sap:filterable="false" sap:label="ID"
        sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
```

b) Supplier (relevant portion only)

```
<EntityType Name="Supplier" sap:content-version="1" sap:is-thing-type="true">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
    </Key>
    <Property MaxLength="10" Name="Id" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String" sap:creatable="false" sap:filterable="false" sap:label="ID"
        sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
    <Property MaxLength="255" Name="Email" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String" sap:creatable="false" sap:filterable="false" sap:label="E-Mail"
        sap:semantics="email" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
```

c) Association

```
<Association Name="PurchaseOrderSupplier" sap:content-version="1" sap:label="Association: Supplier --&gt; Purchase Order">
    <End Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_PurchaseOrderSupplier" Type="EPM_REF_APPS_PO_APV_SRV.Supplier"/>
    <End Multiplicity="*" Role="ToRole_PurchaseOrderSupplier" Type="EPM_REF_APPS_PO_APV_SRV.PurchaseOrder"/>
    <ReferentialConstraint>
        <Principal Role="FromRole_PurchaseOrderSupplier">
            <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
        </Principal>
        <Dependent Role="ToRole_PurchaseOrderSupplier">
            <PropertyRef Name="SupplierId"/>
        </Dependent>
    </ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

The portion of the view (PurchaseOrderDetails.view.xml) is shown below. All the fields, except Email is from the parent, PurchaseOrder entity.

```
<form:SimpleForm class="sapUiForceWidthAuto sapUiResponsiveMargin" columnsL="1" columnsM="1" emptySpanL="5" emptySpanM="5" id="poHeaderForm"
    labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" maxContainerCols="2" minWidth="1024" title="{i18n>xtit.formTitle}">
    <Label id="poIdFormLabel" text="{/#PurchaseOrder/POId/@sap:label}"/>
    <Text id="poIdForm" text="{POId}"/>
    <Label id="addressFormLabel" text="{/#PurchaseOrder/DeliveryAddress/@sap:label}"/>
    <Text id="addressForm" text="{DeliveryAddress}"/>
    <Label id="supplierEmailLabel" text="{/#Supplier/Email/@sap:label}"/>
    <Text id="supplierEmail" text="{/PurchaseOrder/Id/Email}"/>
</form:SimpleForm>
```

I have tried many permutations to bind the field, Email, from the Supplier entity viz: a)  `{/Id/Email}`, b) `{path: 'Supplier' , parameters: {Select 'Email'}}` but the result has been a blank space.

Please show the correct binding syntax for "Email".

Answer (score 2):

Your metadata.xml snippet does not contain a NavigationProperty to the supplier. Therefore, your Association is not recognized... You have to fix your metadata.xml first. After this you can easily do the following:

```
<Text id="supplierEmail" binding="{Supplier}" text="{Email}"/>
```

This assumes that the navigation property of your you have named your NavigationProperty "Supplier" inside your PurchaseOrder Entity. In that case I also suggest you to use `$expand=Supplier` in the binding in order to get the Supplier data in the same request (the one for the PurchaseOrder), i.e. something like this:

```
items="{
    path: '/PurchaseOrderItems',
    parameters: {
        'expand': 'Supplier'
    }
}"
```

After this you could simply use this without the binding attribute because you have 'expanded':

```
<Text id="supplierEmail" text="{Supplier/Email}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Nabi, Thanks for your prompt reply.  1) I did not show the full metadata because of space. But PurchaseOrder Entity has already the following NavigationProperty.  <NavigationProperty FromRole="ToRole_PurchaseOrderSupplier" Name="Supplier" Relationship="EPM_REF_APPS_PO_APV_SRV.PurchaseOrderSupplier"
     ToRole="FromRole_PurchaseOrderSupplier" sap:label="Supplier"/     2) Where should I include $expand=Supplier. Is this in the PurchaseOrderItems.view.xml, beside the field for email.  Thank you

Comment: Hi Nabi, I just tried the following binding syntax in the email field of the PurchaseOrderItems.view.xml and it work !!  >> binding={Supplier}   text={Email}.  Thank you very much for your help in an issue I struggle with for several days.

Comment: I updated the example. Does that finally answer your questions?

Comment: Hi Nabi, No, the syntax I use for binding the "Email" field was:  <Text id="email" binding="{Supplier}" text="{Email}"/> , which worked. Thank you for your help.